# How to train ngram model on my own corpus

Tags: nlp, nltk, n-gram, language-model, trigram

I have a corpus of list of strings:

```
corpus = ["Hello I am Sam", "This is a white desk","I ate cereals", ...]
```

I want to build a language model (preferably using nltk) on this corpus, to get the probability of a word in a sentence. 
So, my later usage will be to get

> P("Sam"| "I am")

in this corpus.
I couldn't find - what is the best way to do so? How to train an ngram model and later get such probabilities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Markov chains https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Very trivial example for your reference.

Assume that you are going to analyse 1-grams.

Analyzed texts:

`monkey eats banana`

`dog eats bone`

unigrams: `monkey`, `eats`,`banana`, `dog`,`bone`, `BEGIN`,`END`.

Each sentence starts with beginning.

Two transitions are possible:

`BEGIN->monkey`

`BEGIN->dog`

This means that there is 50% chance that sentence will begin with `monkey`.

Now after `monkey` there is 100% chance of transition `monkey->eats` (because there was no other `monkey->*` transition in analysed texts.

Now after `eats` there is 50% chance of `banana` and 50% chance of `bone`.

So in general with this model we can generate following sentences:

```
monkey eats banana
monkey eats bone
dog eats bone
dog eats banana
```

each of those has 25% to be produced

Note that bone and banana always transists into `END`

With digrams you will just split it to `monkey eats` -> `banana END`

This is just simplified big picture, hope it helps

**Edit**

As for smoothing mentioned in comment, go with Laplace.

Assume that you did saw each word one more than we really did.

So for example now we will have:

```
eats bone (2)
eats banana (2)
eats chocolate (1)
eats dog (1)
```

Of course in this case we have very small dataset, but for bigger dataset  you will get something like:

```
eats bone (104)
eats banana (1031)
eats chocolate (1)
eats dog (3)
...
```

Comment: for my need I need to use ngram - the problem is how to add smoothing after collected frequencies?

Comment: you can use Laplace, that would mean that would mean just +1 to each occurence. Answer updated

Comment: How do I add it? just add +1 to each entry of the dict?

Comment: Basically yes - but your parameter does not need to equal "1". It can be 0.21 or 3

Comment: and what is the best way to decide it?

Comment: Typically it is set by trial and error, I don't have a rule of thumb for you. Please refer to https://www3.nd.edu/~dchiang/teaching/nlp/2017/notes/chapter10v1.pdf page 74